# Gst.Application.Init() Getting Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: .net, .net-core, video-streaming, gstreamer

Gst.Application.Init() Getting Fatal error. System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Hi team,
Im getting below error when trying to initialize Gst.Application.Init()
I have installed gstreamer in windows machine and using .net core 6 to create the stream.
Any assistance would be much appreciated

```
using Gst.App;
using Gst;

    private void StartGStreamerPipeline()
    {

        Gst.Application.Init();

        // Create the GStreamer pipeline
        var pipeline = new Gst.Pipeline("mypipeline");

        // Create pipeline elements
        var source = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("v4l2src", "source");
        var convert = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("videoconvert", "convert");
        var encoder = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("x264enc", "encoder");
        var parser = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("h264parse", "parser");
        var payloader = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("rtph264pay", "payloader");
        var sink = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("appsink", "sink");

        // Configure elements and add them to the pipeline
        pipeline.Add(source, convert, encoder, parser, payloader, sink);
        source.Link(convert);
        convert.Link(encoder);
        encoder.Link(parser);
        parser.Link(payloader);
        payloader.Link(sink);

        // Configure the appsink element for receiving video data
        var appSink = sink as Gst.App.AppSink;
        appSink.EmitSignals = true;
        appSink.Caps = Gst.Caps.FromString("video/x-h264");
        appSink.NewSample += AppSinkNewSample;

        // Start the pipeline
        pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
        Clients.All.SendAsync("Receivepipeline", pipeline);
    }
```